# I'm getting TypeError: Cannot setitem on a Categorical with a new category (Less than 35), set the categories first

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with columns Age and MedianValue.  Both are numeric.  I want to bucket the Age variable into 3 groups and then perform an ANOVA analysis.  When I try to create the buckets, I get TypeError: Cannot setitem on a Categorical with a new category (Less than 35), set the categories first

Here's what I tried:

```
df.loc[(df['AGE'] <= 35), 'age_group'] = 'Less than 35'
df.loc[(df['AGE'] > 35)&(df["AGE"] < 70), 'age_group'] = '35 to 70'
df.loc[(df['AGE'] > 70), 'age_group'] = 'Over 70'

# Separate samples into a variable each
a = df[df['age_group'] == "Less than 35"]["MEDV"]
b = df[df['age_group'] == "35 to 70"]["MEDV"]
c = df[df['age_group'] == "Over 70"]["MEDV"]

f_statistic, p_value = stats.f_oneway(a, b, c)
print("F_Statistic: {0}, P-Value: {1}".format(f_statistic,p_value))
```

The error is throwing on the first line. I'm in a Jupyter notebook running python 3.10

I have used this type of code before in other environments.  Either I'm missing something or was there a change in 3.10?

Comment: @toyota Please don't use the [tag:python3] tag unless the question is version-specific, and even then, include the [tag:python] tag too.

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. For specifics, see [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](/q/20109391/4518341).

Answer (score 0):

I solved this using cut to create the age groups first and then add them to the dataframe

```
# Create the age groups
age_groups = pd.cut(df['AGE'], bins=[0, 35, 70, 100], labels=['Less than 35', '35 to 70', 'Over 70'])

# Add the age groups to the dataframe
df['age_group'] = age_groups

# Separate samples into a variable each
a = df[df['age_group'] == "Less than 35"]["MEDV"]
b = df[df['age_group'] == "35 to 70"]["MEDV"]
c = df[df['age_group'] == "Over 70"]["MEDV"]

# Perform ANOVA analysis
f_statistic, p_value = stats.f_oneway(a, b, c)

# Print the results
print("F_Statistic: {0}, P-Value: {1}".format(f_statistic, p_value))`age_groups = pd.cut(df['AGE'], bins=[0, 35, 70, 100], labels=['Less than 35', '35 to 70', 'Over 70'])
```